# Qt issue passing arguments to slot

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, signals-slots

I can't seem to pass an argument to a slot.  If I don't pass an argument, the function rolls through fine.  If I pass an argument (integer), I get the errors "No such name type" and  "No such slot" when I compile.

In my header, I declare:

```
private slots:
void addButton(int);
signals:
void clicked(int)
```

in my Main.cpp, I do:

```
int count;
int count = 0;
QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("Button");
_layout->addWidget(button);
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked(count), this, SLOT(addButton(count)));
```

....

```
void Main::addButton(int count) {

//do stuff with count

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sebastian is correct that you cannot do this in the way you're trying, however Qt does provide a class that gives you the functionality you want.

Check out the [QSignalMapper](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html). It allows you to associate an integer with an object/signal pair. You then connect to its signals instead of directly to the button.

Answer (score 8):

The signal and the slot must have the same number and type(s) of argument(s), and you can only pass the argument(s) of the signal to the slot, not any variable or value that you want.

Comment: Edited the code above to reflect what I tried (based on an example I found), but still doesn't work.

Comment: The clicked()-signal is defined by the button class, you cannot change that (unless you write your own button class and do so, but I doubt that this is the solution to whatever you are trying to do here).

Answer (score 3):

I can see three problems with this.

Firstly, the `clicked()` signal is emitted by `QPushButton` (with no parameters), but you're trying to redefine it in your own class (with an `int` parameter). If you want to do this:

```
SignalClass* objectWithSignals = new SignalClass;
SlotClass* objectWithSlots = new SlotClass;
connect(objectWithSignals, SIGNAL(a()), objectWithSlots, SLOT(b()));
```

then you can only connect to the signals already defined in `SignalClass`. In other words, the signal `a()` must belong to `SignalClass`, not `SlotClass`.

(In fact, `clicked()` is defined in `QPushButton`'s base class [`QAbstractButton`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qabstractbutton.html).)

Secondly, inside the `connect()` function, you need to specify the signal and slot signatures with their parameter **types**. Where you have `count` inside the `connect()` function, it should be `int`.

And thirdly, there's a bracket missing in your call to connect: `SIGNAL(clicked(count))`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am surprised that yours is the only answer that mentions the argument error where a variable's name is passed to SIGNAL and SLOT in the connect call; the sample code will never compile unless "count" is a type.