# QT: No Such Slot

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt-creator, signals-slots

Problem is that I keep getting the 'No Such Slot' runtime error in Qt Creator every time I launch a 'settings' window from my main window. I've found Qt to be quite counter-intuitive so far and this slots 'n signals concept seems a bit of a stretch from simply passing vars or function calls. Basically, I have menu with a settings option, that when clicked, opens a settings window which needs to grab a double from the user and update a var in the main window.

SettingsWindow.h

```
class SettingsWindow : public QWidget
{
      Q_OBJECT
  public:
      SettingsWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
  signals:
      void ValChanged(double newVal);
  public slots:
      void Accept();
  private:
      QLineEdit *le1;
};
```

The settings window has an accept button which calls Accept() which emits the ValChanged signal with newVal set as the user input in le1 as a double.

SettingsWindow.cpp

```
void SettingsWindow::Accept(){
    emit ValChanged(le1->text().toDouble());
    this->close();
}
```

This settings window is called by the application's main window: MainWindow

MainWindow.cpp

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
      Q_OBJECT  
  public:
      MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
  public slots:
      void SetVal(double x);
  private slots:
      void NewWindow();
  private:
      double theVal;
};
```

This main window has a menu which one would select settings from. This creates a new window with a field for one to enter a number.

MainWindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::NewWindow()
{
    SettingsWindow *MySettings=new SettingsWindow(this);
    QObject::connect(MySettings, SIGNAL(ValChanged(double)), this, SLOT(SetVal(double)));
    MySettings->show();
    MySettings->raise();
}

void MainWindow::SetVal(double x){
    theVal = x;
}
```

My hope is that when the settings window is opened, the user can enter a val into the field which then emits the ValChanged Signal which sets theVal to the value specified by the user. Most of the time I saw an issue with people not including Q_OBJECT macro, but I've included it both times. Any suggestions on why this doesn't work?

Comment: Is you moc file alright ? Can you see your slot in the `qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void **_a)` ?

Comment: Yeah, it's in there. It should all be defined.

Comment: A couple questions for clarification.. Which slot is named in the error message for "No such slot"? How is the "Accept" slot called?

Comment: Object::connect: No such slot MainWindow::SetVal(double x)

Comment: @user850275: Either you misquoted the error message, or you miscopied your code. The error message should be `No such slot: MainWindow::SetVal(double)` (without the `x`). If the error message is correct, and your code is really `SLOT(SetVal(double x))`, then you can fix the problem by removing the `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are having is almost certainly due to a moc file not being recreated, a typo in your call to connect or a typo in the declaration of the slot in question.

You may want to consider that this is a lot more work than necessary for getting input from a dialog. A simpler method would be to connect the "Accept" button clicked signal to a slot in main window and then fetch the value you want directly from the instance of the settings window through a `getXXX()` method.

If you eventually have a settings dialog with a lot of values, instead of fetching each value through getters, have the "Accept" button signal return a structure with all the values as fields of that structure.

I should mention that it looks like `NewWindow()` creates a new instance of `SettingsWindow` each time it is called. All of these instances will persist until the `MainWindow` is destroyed.

Comment: Hmm, I shall consider this. I wish someone would have published that in the tutorials or something along the way. I'm also quite aware that of the instances left open till MainWindow's destructor, this is merely a proof of concept moment.

Comment: I can understand your frustration, especially if you haven't worked with windowing frameworks before. It is a vast library to become familiar with. Qt is among the best documented libraries you will find and rich with examples and demos. Unfortunately most of them are very targeted at a single item and are lacking in comprehensive, best practice "application" examples. Sometimes you will find one of the demo or examples will have valuable information as a side effect. The Qt programmers here are friendly and helpful so keep the questions coming.

Comment: Well thanks for the help! I decided to use your described method of setting up a getter to do the work, and it appears to be working now. Consider this solved.

Answer (score 7):

For me, adding a `public Q_SLOTS:` above my slot function was what I was missing. (I already had Q_OBJECT, etc.)

Comment: Please specify that. It is not clear to me what exactly you did.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem when I manually recreated my moc file on the command line.

I used qt command prompt option so all the paths had been set:

```
cd /path/to/my/project
moc -o moc_myheaderfile.cpp myheaderfile.h
```

There was nothing wrong with my code, and my makefile didn't have any moc command I could see. This works for all my examples I have tried. I hope someone might try this too. I experimented for almost 85 hours before I could find the cause.

For codeblocks users, try recreating your moc files to be precise.
the `-o myheaderfile.cpp` option is to save the moc output to a file.
Running moc on the file actually spews everything onto the console window.

Answer (score 0):

I was incorrectly trying to pass a parameter to my slot without a `QSignalMapper`, which I learned from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160321/qt-issue-passing-arguments-to-slot) SO post.

Removing all parameters to the slot function (.h and .cpp) allowed the callback to be found and called.

Yes, I'm a Qt n00b. Time to refactor with QSignalMapper :)

HTH